# Express catch all route excluding static content such as css and js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

New to Node.js.

I'm using the VS2015 Express 3 template. How can I write my routing to:

- Have a page at "/"
- Have a a catch all route that responds with the home page "/"
- Doesn't interfere with JS and CSS files

I.e., I tried the following, but then the JS and CSS files in the public directory respond with 404 don't render or execute. I thought that the static files code would handle it, but it does not. It works until I add the block with "*".

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.send('/', 404);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: If you're' really just trying to add a 404 handler, then see here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-404-responses

Comment: Express `static` middleware **must** be defined before all other middlewares: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`, place it after `app.set('view engine', 'jade');`

Comment: Here's a good article on doing proper 404 and 500 error handling in node.js: http://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-custom-error-pages-404-and-500.html.  `app.get('*',...)` is NOT how you should be doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as suggested by jfriend00, is to add the following line below app.get('/', routes.index):

```
app.use(routes.index);
```